# AutoResetEvent Reset method

Tags: c#, reset, autoresetevent

Could someone introduce an use case for AutoResetEvent.Reset() method ?
When and why I would like to use this method ?
I understand WaitOne and Set but this is quite unclear for me.

Comment: Why a vote to close?  This question seems perfectly clear and useful to me...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes the `AutoResetEvent` will automatically reset it's state whenever a thread which is waiting on the event is signaled.  However it's possible that a given event is no longer valid and no thread has waited on an `AutoResetEvent` since it was originally set.  In that scenario the `Reset` method becomes useful

Comment: But what is a benefit on calling Reset() in such case ?

Comment: @anth it prevents any thread which hasn't yet called wait, but will at some point in the future, from being activated for an event which is no longer valid.  Note: This in itself is not enough to prevent a race condition but it can be a part of a larger solution

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's just inherited from [EventWaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.aspx). Probably more useful with the ManualResetEvent which also inherits from that class?

Answer (score 1):

The method is inherited from the base class `EventWaitHandle` and is used to (re)set an `AutoResetEvent` to its "blocked" state.

Because `AutoResetEvent` will automatically enter that state as soon as it's signalled, you'll typically never see this method used in code, but for other classes deriving from `EventWaitHandle` it would be much more useful!

Answer (score 1):

If the AutoResetEvent producer wants to clear the event, you would use Reset().  This way, you can safely "reset" the event without having to know if it's currently signaled.  If the producer used WaitOne to "reset" it's own event, there is a risk that you could deadlock (i.e. never return since the event isn't signaled and the producer thread is blocked).

Answer (score 1):

**Reset**:

> Sets the state of the event to nonsignaled
>   ,See [EventWaitHandle Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.aspx)

Sample,

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
namespace ThreadingInCSharp.Signaling
{
    class Program
    {
        static EventWaitHandle _waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //The event's state is Signal
            _waitHandle.Set();
            new Thread(Waiter).Start();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            _waitHandle.Set();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        private static void Waiter()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm Waiting...");
            _waitHandle.WaitOne();
            //The word pass will print immediately 
            Console.WriteLine("pass");
        }
    }
}
```

Using **Reset**,

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
namespace ThreadingInCSharp.Signaling
{
    class Program
    {
        static EventWaitHandle _waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //The event's state is Signal
            _waitHandle.Set();
            _waitHandle.Reset();
            new Thread(Waiter).Start();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            _waitHandle.Set();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void Waiter()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm Waiting...");
            _waitHandle.WaitOne();
            //The word will wait 2 seconds for printing
            Console.WriteLine("pass");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ManualResetEvent when using Reset(), as AutoResetEvent resets itself when a thread has become signaled.